# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] does not return the expected directory location

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I accessed the sub-folder of my website and got this error:

```
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/var/www/html//include/version.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /srv/sparrow/php/include/branches.inc on line 3
```

It seems that **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** return a wrong directory like this:

```
/var/www/html/
```

If I access *www.my.website/php*, this should be the expected directory that the **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** should return:

```
/var/www/html/php/
```

These are my virtualhost configurations:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName   www.mywebsite.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

   <Directory /var/www/html/>
     Options -Indexes -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName   www.mywebsite.com/ph
  # Webroot of PHP site
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/php/

  <Directory /var/www/html/php/>
    Options -Indexes -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I configure my virtualhost configurations such that if I access www.my.website/php it should return the DocumentRoot with value /var/www/html/php/ ?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Document root has __fixed__ value. Any path on your site you should append to document root __manually__

Comment: Thanks @u_mulder. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two vhosts on port 80 present. The first wins. You should distinguish them by IP, servername or port. If both run on the same port you'll also need `NameVirtualHost 80` if you're using Apache 2.2 (not necessary for 2.4).

I am pretty sure, if you swap the vhosts, you will get `/var/www/html/php/` for `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

But still:
**If you have two vhosts, make them distinguishable!**

---

**Update**

Additional rewrite (requires `mod_rewrite` to be activated) in upper vhost, so you can drop the second vhost:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/ph/(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ph/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or `[P,L]` if you want to hide that you are rewriting, but `[P]` requires `mod_proxy` to be activated as well.

Comment: Hi @Hello Fishy, thanks for answering my question. I added servername for each vhosts to distinguish them and it doesn't work. I followed this documentation of NameVirtualHost. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: ´www.mywebsite.com/ph´ is not a servername :( `/ph` is the URI and `www.mywebsite.com` is a servername...so both vhosts still listen to the same port and name -> can't work...either one should have another port or another name. Btw, do you really need two vhosts anyway?

Comment: Yes, I really need them. If I visit www.mywebsitemcom/ph, it should use the second vhost. If not, then errors will occur because documentroot is not correct. Thanks Hello Fishy for your help.

Comment: But you won't need an additional vhost just for that. Just add a RewriteRule like the one above (gimme 2mins^^)

Comment: Thanks Hello Fishy. +1

Comment: I will test it. :) I have a last question, if I access www.mywebsite.com/ph, does it change the documentroot to var/www/html/php? Thanks Hello Fishy.

Comment: No, DocumentRoot will stay the same, it is initialized on server-startup not on runtime :/ But as soon as you have another domain-name like www.new.mydomain.com you can set this as `ServerName` for the second vhost and configure a second DocumentRoot there.

Comment: It sounds that I need to setup another domain name. Each vhost must have different documentroot. Thanks Hello Fishy

Comment: You don't really have to change the DocumentRoot. I mean, if you want to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` why not just add `/php` as a string to that, by concatenation?! You could even set an environment variable with the value of your DocumentRoot, 'add' `/php` to that and use this env-var in your PHP-code...

Comment: I was thinking to that idea but we have no control to the php files. We just only cloning the php files and anytime it may update. There is a chance that the php file that I modified will be override by the updated ones.

Comment: But shouldn't the variable stay the same? So if you set a env-var on Apache-side (modified to fit your needs) and call that env-var in PHP code without further manipulation, shouldn't that be good enough?

Comment: Hi @Hello Fishy, that is a good idea. Will use that idea. Thanks.